# Wekan - Wysiwyg Editor disappearing after updating from 6.98 to 6.99 or later

Tags: docker

I'm using wekan via Docker (https://hub.docker.com/r/wekanteam/wekan) to host a small Trello-Clone.

Recently after updating, I recognized that the Rich-Text editor was gone. Now I played a bit and it is obviously lost during the step from 6.98 (Rich-Text Editor working) to 6.99 (no Rich-Text editor anymore).

When opening a card with existing "Rich Text", in View mode everything looks good, but when opening the textbox for editing, it shows the plain HTML.

Google didn't help me yet, also I didn't find anything in the wekan release notes regarding a change in config or s.th. like that.

Also the most recent versions show this.

Did anyone encounter the same and know how to fix it?

Comment: There is a related [issue in a newer version](https://github.com/wekan/wekan/issues/5178). Have you tried updating to the version where this is supposed to be fixed?

Comment: If not, raising an issue would be the way to proceed.

Comment: Thanks @GeraldSchneider, this made the trick. That "Convert to Markdown" Button on the first view looks like some charset issue, shown right over the html ;) The conversion doesn't cover everything but at least the text is somehow readable now and can be adapted with a bit of manual work where needed.